# Oauth2 with asp.net mvc and dynamics ax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, axapta

I am working on my intern ship project and I need to make an API with Oauth2 authorization on some Dynamics AX web services. The goal is that a third party can register on the oauth server and can call some endpoints to let the user authenticate himself and access the user's data over mobile.

I am very new to all this and I am not sure how or where to make this. I haven't found much about Oauth2 with dynamic AX. Do I need to make all the oauth services in the asp.net website then? I find it also a bit hard to find good tutorials on the matter, are there any tutorials you suggest?

Comment: You may need to make a 'proxy' web service that hosts the Oauth2 authorization in .NET, and that calls Dynamics AX from there --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa877498.aspx

Comment: So if I where to use ASP.NET mvc for this it would be an okay solution?

Comment: My understanding of ASP.NET mvc is that it's a framework to 'hang' your code on, so that will work fine.  
Remember the Dyn AX Web Services uses a Business Connector (a special/generic user) and you will be passing as a parameter each user's id to query data.